# NSRegularExpression Help

Tags: iphone, regex, cocoa

I want parse, with iPhone's NSRegularExpression class, this text:

```
<td class="rowhead">Uploaded</td><td align="left">652.81 GB</td>
```

for extract **Uploaded** and **652.81** text.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any sample of the code that you've tried, and what's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do think that an xml parser is more suited to parsing xml, here are some regexes:

given the input string specified and replacing with the first group:

`[^>]*>([^<]*)<.*` results in `Uploaded`

`.*>([^<]*)<.*` results in `652.81 GB`

You can probably simplify it a little further, but this works.

Comment: Thank's very much. Your code it's perfect for my goal! i love you! :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a good write-up on how to strip html in Objective c:

http://rudis.net/content/2009/01/21/flatten-html-content-ie-strip-tags-cocoaobjective-c

You can also use NSXMLParser to get specific fields, or use a UIWebView and a javascript selector.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I'll want try http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/

Answer (score 0):

This string work perfectly for check the link on a html page:

```
<a href\s*=\s*\"([^\"]*)\">([^<]*)</a>
```

I have try rewrite the regex for my goal, but don't work :(

```
<td\\s*([^\"]*)>([^\"]*)\">([^<]*)</td>
```